# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

The method is working fine and it does what I want on the back-end but I am getting the following error in the console:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

The above error is caught in the `catch`.

I read out similiar questions which suggests to add value for the headers, but didn't fix it either.

```
let serverURL = URL(string: "https://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/email")
self.request = URLRequest(url:serverURL!)
self.request?.httpMethod = "POST"
self.request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
self.request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

 do {
      self.request?.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postContent, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
  }
```

The json has this format: `postContent: [String: String]`,  `["email": "myemail@domain.com"]`

The code for task:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    if (self.activityIndicator != nil) {
        self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: self.activityIndicator!)
    }

    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:String]

        if let parseJSON = json {
        self.alertMessage(message: "Please check your email for instructions.")
            }
        } else {
            self.alertMessage(message: "Invalid email address!")
        }
    } catch {
        self.alertMessage(message: "Could not send request. Try again!")
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo mistake. Did you try to change

```
self.request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
```

to

```
self.request?.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: This doesn't make any change.

Comment: I am getting nil on `json`

Comment: @MaihanNijat : did you try to change your `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) ` to `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) `

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `200` OK response but the json body was returned empty:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:String]
```

I modified the API and added body to response to fix this.

Comment: There is no reason to use `.mutableContainers` in Swift.